# Android layout border won't apply

Tags: android

I'm building a simple UI for my app, it's supposed to look like this :

[image: What i have]

You can see the problem easily, the corners are not rendering great, the gray background of the top layout is overriding the border of the main layout. My XML sounds like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundroundedcorners"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPostAuthor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPostDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPostContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean faucibus risus eget convallis imperdiet. Cras tempus ante eros, auctor ornare odio vulputate nec. Quisque id vehicula tellus. Nulla adipiscing elit ipsum, a venenatis purus luctus porta. Aliquam in odio elementum, feugiat augue sit amet, sagittis dolor. Vestibulum vitae molestie risus. Sed eleifend libero est, nec scelerisque elit venenatis eu. Vivamus nulla tortor, accumsan nec sapien consectetur, semper placerat sem. Nullam imperdiet libero enim, vitae interdum nunc suscipit et. Nulla lacinia urna congue elit dictum, id adipiscing nulla eleifend. Quisque felis tellus, elementum eget tempus nec, sagittis sit amet nisl. Phasellus ut neque justo. Etiam mattis tempor condimentum." />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the background XML file : (backgroundroundedcorners.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `background drawable` with `GRAY color` and same `corner radius` as the `main  layout`. But set `corner radius` only for `topRight` and `topLeft`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#f0f0f0"/>
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

And, set this as the `background` of `inner LinearLayout layout`

Comment: Works perfectly, but only on the device. In Eclipse's layout renderer, the previous problem is still present. But whatever, it works ^^